# Conflicto con URL en React JS, no me reconoce librerias

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en React, el tema es el siguiente:
Se dio el caso que tengo una URL con doble barra dentro de la URL es decir : "localhost:3000/tienda/tienda", cuando la URL posee esta característica no me reconoce las librerías de jQuery, Bootstrap y Popper, pero si solamente pongo :

```
<Route path="/tienda" exact component={Tienda} />
```

Con esta URL cuando accedo funciona y me reconoce las librerias de Jquery, popper, etc todo OK.

Ahora si yo pongo:

```
<Route path="/tienda/tienda" exact component={Tienda} />
```

Aca ya no me reconoce las librerias.

PD: Me doy cuenta que no me reconoce las librerias debido a que tengo un menu que no colapsa, el ejemplo es este:

```
const ItemFiltro = props => {

  return (
    <div className='card card-collapse'>
      <div className='card-header' role='tab' id={props.headerId}>
        <h5 className='mb-0'>
          <a
            data-toggle='collapse'
            href={`#${props.colapseId}`}
            aria-expanded='true'
            aria-controls={props.colapseId}
          >
            {props.titulo}
            <i className='material-icons'>keyboard_arrow_down</i>
          </a>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div
        id={props.colapseId}
        className='collapse show'
        role='tabpanel'
        aria-labelledby={props.headerId}
      >
        <div className='card-body card-refine'>
          <ItemFiltroCheck item='Lenovo' />
          <ItemFiltroCheck item='Acer' />
          <ItemFiltroCheck item='HP' />
          <ItemFiltroCheck item='MSI' />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ItemFiltro
```

He tratado de importar las librerias en mi index.html y mi App.js y no me funciona.
En index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#212121" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>StoreSys - Tienda Online</title>
    <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons"
    />

    <!-- CSS Files -->
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--   Core JS Files       -->
    <script src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/bootstrap-material-design.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/material-kit.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/js/all.js"
      data-auto-a11y="true"
    ></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Al no funcionar esto, lo que hice fue en mi App.js :

```
function App() {
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(async () => {
    appendScript("./assets/js/jquery.min.js");
    appendScript("./assets/js/popper.min.js");
    appendScript("./assets/js/bootstrap-material-design.min.j");
    appendScript("./assets/js/moment.min.js");
    appendScript("./assets/js/material-kit.min.js");
  },[]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    setEmail(window.localStorage.getItem("emailForRegistration"));
    if (email != "" && email != null) {
      await currentUser({ email })
        .then((res) => {
          dispatch({
            type: "LOGGED_IN_USER",
            payload: {
              name: res.data[0].Nombre,
              email: res.data[0].Mail,
              apellido: res.data[0].Apellido,
              id_usuarios_tipos: res.data[0].id_usuarios_tipos,
              _id: res.data[0].id,
            },
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  }, [email]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="sidebar-collapse">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="separador"></div>
        <Encabezado />
        <div className="main main-raised">
          <div className="container">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Menu} />
              <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
              <Route path="/registro" exact component={Registro} />
              <Route path="/tienda/tienda" exact component={Tienda} />
              <Route path="/carrito" exact component={Carrito} />
              <Route path="/articulo/:id" exact component={Articulo} />
              <Route path="/formas-pago" exact component={FormasDePago} />
              <Route exact path="/pagoMp/success/:idPago" component={PagoAprobado} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Pero sigue sin funcionarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que la url de tus imports está relativo a la url de donde estás parado (`./assets/js/...`) siendo el `.` el que indica una ruta relativa desde donde estás en el `pathname`.

Intenta con:

```
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-material-design.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/material-kit.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ! Me funciono